# Xamarin Forms - ListviewSelectedItem MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Im unable to set the selectedItem in a listview control. Ive set the binding context and can debug the code without issue. Onload of the form I can see the get and set method being called but when I select an item in the listview the set is not called. I cannot understand why

```
    private NavigationItems _SelectedNavigationItem;
    public NavigationItems SelectedNavigationItem
    {
        get { return _SelectedNavigationItem; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                _SelectedNavigationItem = value;
                NavigateToPage(value);   
            }
        }
    }

    public async void NavigateToPage(NavigationItems selectedItem )
    {
        switch (selectedItem.Id)
        {
            case "Appointments":
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyAppointments());
                break;
            case "Companies":
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Companies());
                break;
            case "Messages":
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Messages());
                break;
            default:              
                break;
        }
    }
```

View

```
            <!-- Navigation -->
            <ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="20,30,20,10" Grid.Row="1"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding NavigationCollection}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNavigationItem}"
                      HasUnevenRows="false"                      
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell >

                                <Grid Padding="5,5,5,5" >
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <!--Icon-->
                                    <Image Aspect="AspectFit" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="18" WidthRequest="18"  Source="{Binding Icon}"/>

                                    <!--Navigation Name-->
                                    <Label Margin="10,0,30,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource SecondaryLabelStyle}" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium"/>

                                    <!--Navigation Totals-->
                                    <Frame VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource CircleFrameStyle}">
                                        <Label TextColor="#d2d2d2"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Total}" FontSize="Small">
                                            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ForgotPassword}" />
                                            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        </Label>
                                    </Frame>

                                </Grid>

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Everything appears to be in order but something strange is happening. Ive also tried setting mode=TwoWay explicitly in the xaml but I know listview mode is twoway by default.

Kevin

Comment: Strange. You don't get in the setter? Not even at the null check? Do other bindings work? Did you set the `BindingContext`? By the way, not to be a smartass, but the binding mode is `OneWayToSource` not `TwoWay` by default :)

Comment: That's the very odd thing about it. When the page first loads I see the Get and Set being called. I check for Null in the setter to ignore so I know the binding context is working as expected.

Comment: Ivw added a button that calls a command which updates a property to set an entry control. all is working fine. its just the listview control

Answer (score 0):

I think doing your setter code this way will solve your problems

```
private NavigationItems _SelectedNavigationItem;
    public NavigationItems SelectedNavigationItem
    {
        get { return _SelectedNavigationItem; }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedNavigationItem != value)
            {
                _SelectedNavigationItem = value;
                NavigateToPage(value);   
            }
        }
    }
```